# RFID/NFC (13.56 MHz), is it possible to send raw bytes and receive response?

Tags: arduino-uno, rf, rfid

I'm trying to implement a card reader (i.e. credit cards) for shopping purposes, and AFAIK those cards are ISO 14443-A compliant (Mifare Classic 1K). I already made an Android app that can send custom APDU to read specific sectors by using raw SendBytes().

Since I need to build a circuit with a custom antenna, I chose Arduino-uno with a NFC module (was thinking about StrongLink SL013), I wanted to know if it's possible to send raw bytes and receive the response from the tag. I only found some higher-level implementation (readSector, writeSector and so on).

Comment: Have you gone through the technical specifications? Have you read the ISO-14443-A definitions? This should be directly answerable from the specifications.

Comment: I found it's not part of the ISO specifications, it depends on the specific chipset/shield i'm using. NXP PN532 supports it.

Answer (score 1):

RFID protocols require either passive or active tags.  Depending on which you use, either the tag or reader regularly transmits pulses.  Check www.rfidreader.com for more info.  https://www.rfidjournal.com provides valuable resources as well.

Many companies invest heavily in developing RFID technology.  You would be well advised not to reinvent wheels without reeeeally deeeeeep pockets.

Answer (score 1):

This would differ per device/reader.
Currently, I'm in a project with a TRF7970a RFID reader. I've seen it it's datasheet that it does have options to send RAW values as it does not support every protocol (NXP has patent on one?) thus the chip doesn,t parse it, but can send it to the mcu completely.
In short, yes this is possible.
But using a reader that is compliant with your protocol might supress your development cost/time